# Validate letters in real time and manipulate them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a div with contenteditable and I'm trying to manipulate the array of this div to check if each letter written inside it, is the same as the letter on another text, based on the index.

The validation is done, I can check it, my problem is that, I need to change the letter color to red, if the letter don't validate. And I'm having trouble inserting a span with the class that I want.

Anyone have a sugestion?

Code follows:

```
 timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
    $('#countdown .values').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString(['minutes', 'seconds']));

    if ($('.true-textarea').contents().get(0)) {
      var textResult = $(".true-textarea").contents().get(0).nodeValue;
      var textSize = textResult().length - 1;
    }

    $(".true-textarea").on("keypress", function(e) {
      var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
      e.preventDefault();

      $(".true-textarea").html("");

      if (c != textFake[textSize]) {
        $(".true-textarea").addClass("red-border");
        cls = "color-red";
      } else {
        cls = "color-purple";
        $(".true-textarea").removeClass("red-border");
      }

      console.log('result', textResult);
      console.log('size', textSize)

      res += "<span class='"+cls+"'>"+c+"</span>";
      cls = "";

      $(".true-textarea").html(res);
   });
  });
```

Comment: Please include the applicable code so we can help!

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: *"I'm trying to manipulate the array of this div"* - Do you mean the *content* of this div?

Comment: update with code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So after hours trying to figure this out I came up if this code.

Used some examples that I saw in around the internet, fixed some problems, and it's working with the following code:

```
function focusAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
      && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(el);
      range.collapse(false);
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);

    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
      var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
      textRange.moveToElementText(el);
      textRange.collapse(false);
      textRange.select();
    }
  }

  $('.true-textarea').unbind();
  $('.true-textarea').focus();

  timer.start({countdown: true, startValues: {seconds: 60}});

  $('#countdown .values').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString(['minutes', 'seconds']));

  var res = "", cls = "";


  textResult.on("keypress", function(e){

    textResult.find('br').remove();

    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    e.preventDefault();

    res = textResult.html();

    textSize = textResult.text().length;

    if (c === textFake[textSize]) {
      cls = "color-purple";
    } else {
      cls = "color-red";
    }

    res += "<span class='"+cls+"'>"+c+"</span>";

    var del = false;

    var lastFocused;

    cls = "";

    textResult.html(res);

    focusAtEnd($(this).get(0));
  })
```